# Python Paramiko: Use PKCS#11 compliant smart card

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys, pkcs#11

Is there a way to use PKCS#11 compliant smart card with Python Paramiko for SSH authentication ?

In OpenSSH, it supports option `PKCS11Provider` for ssh authentication via smart cards. However, [Paramiko documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/keys.html) does not mention support for PKCS#11.

OR, Is there any other way apart from Paramiko to use SSH Smart card for authentication.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: A lot of years ago, I got this working using agent forwarding (to an out-of-process agent written in C).

Answer (score 0):

The feature has not been merged or released yet, but this PR includes a branch you can use to enable pkcs11 support for Paramiko.  Hopefully, eventually this will be a native feature in Paramiko.

https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/1804